# TypeError must be str, not int in string slicing in Python

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to write a simple function in python to do what in or str.contains does, here are the codes:

```
def contains(big, little):
  length = len(little_string)
  for i in big:
    if big[i:i+length-1] == little:
      return True
  return False
```

For line ``` if big[i:i+length-1] == little:`` it throws a TypeError saying must be str not int ``` and I'm baffled. Since I think as long as big is a string the slicing of it will certainly be string too.

Does anyone know why this happened? thanks a lot.

Comment: if `big` is a `str`, then `for i in big` will yield characters of the string

Comment: Please include an example of how you called the function and the fill error message. You most probably wanted to write `for i in len(big)`.

Comment: @DYZ `for i in range(len(big))`.

Comment: @chepner Sure...

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is to iterate over a range, not over the string `big` itself:

```py
big = 'abcd'

for i in big:
    print(i)
a
b
c
d

for i in range(len(big)):
    print(i)
0
1
2
3
```

This is what's causing your error, you are passing *characters* of `big` into your slice and then adding them to `int`. The `TypeError` is from the addition of the two, not the slice:

```py
'a' + 1
TypeError: must be str, not int

big = 'abcd'
big['a': 'a'+1]
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

To fix this, create a `range(len(big))` which produces those integer indices, which match the types, and the slice will work:

```
def contains(big, little):
    l = len(little)
    ## Do this instead
    # i is now an int in the range of len(big)
    for i in range(len(big)):
        if b[i:i + l] == little:
            return True
    return False
```

You also don't need the `-1` in your slice, since slicing will not produce an `IndexError`

Comment: yes i just realised that ! thanks so much for the clarifying example

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of little errors in the code you show us. For starters, a typo where you calculate `len(little_string)` while your parameter is called `little`.

The core of the issue as you describe is because `for in in big` effectively loops through the characters of the `big` string, which is not what you want to do in the code. Since you are looking at moving by index, then you should rather do something like this:

```
def contains(big, little):
    length = len(little)                 # fix the typo
    for i in range(len(big)):            # this generates list of indices [0,1,2...]
        if big[i:i + length] == little:  # note we fixed it removing -1
            return True
    return False

# test
needle = 'one'
haystack = 'dragone'

print(contains(haystack, needle))
>> True
```

Comment: thanks so much for the explanation (and the little notes)!